# Bootproblems after second OS installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

My Problem:

I had Windows 7 on my old HDD. Bought 120GB SSD to install Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dualboot. Disabled HDD. Windows installation -> create 60GB partition for WIN7, works.
Next: Ubuntu installation -> create 60GB partition out of the empty space of the ssd, works! reboot: Grub -> choose windows7 loader, 1 second dark, reopens grub. ubuntu still works. If i enable my HDD a second win7 loader is in the grub bootlist, works.

Please tell me how can i fix it, thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to fix?  Are you trying to remove the second GRUB entry for your Windows installation?  From your post it sounds like you are still able to access both Windows and Ubuntu.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I try to start the new windows from the ssd it always reopens grub and I have to choose again. Before the installation of Ubuntu win7 on the ssd worked. I think we can ignore the hdd. My Problem is just that I cant start Win7. I tried to fix grub with: "sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb" and reinstalled ubuntu. The grub manager can find the win7 but could not start it.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting a Ubuntu live CD and installing and running boot-repair.  Saved me from booting problems many times.  Hope this helps!

http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/